# How to move the home directory to another partition?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning

I created a partition in my hard disk for my data (documents, multimedia, etc.).
How can I:

1. Move the `/home/` directory to the new partition
2. Make the OS (Ubuntu Linux) treat that directory as the default `/home/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you just move all the stuff in `/home` to the new partition and then mount that partition at `/home` by editing the `/etc/fstab` file.

See [here](http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/01/29/move-home-to-its-own-partition/) for a walk through.